# Laravel 5 | How to programmatically set class aliasses?

Tags: php, laravel, models, laravel-5.1

I am currently working on a module system in Laravel 5.
Currently in Laravel 5, you need to do it like this in the config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
  ...other classes...
  'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
]
```

What I would like to do is, somewhere inside the main model of my module, set that or other models as an alias. So I don't need to change my config file every time I install or uninstall a module.

Anyone got a solution? Been trying this for a few days now, and I can't find a solution yet! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [`class_alias` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) that Laravel uses as well. You can just do this:

```
class_alias(The\Real\Class::class, 'TheAlias');
```

Comment: Hmm that's a good point :D I didn't know there was such a function. So when I use this with the module config in my `ModulesServiceProvider.php` I think it might work! Thanks :)

Comment: How about Lazy loading them ? Will that work automatically with this function as well ?

Comment: Lazy loading has nothing to do with `class_alias`. This function just creates an alias so you might access the original class under another name.